# LED Strips: Is thermal glue a suitable compound to be used with them and allow for heat dissipation?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have a project where I will be building a LED light panel onto a ceramic floor and wall tiles. As you know LED stripes to come with a 3M sticky adhesive which generally does the job fairly well however due to the LEDs creating heat I would like to TAP into the heat conductivity of ceramic which means I should be able to run high powered LEDS without worrying about a heatsink, or at least that's what I hope!

My question is simple, will the compound be okay to use on top of the 3m Adhesive?

Comment: you can get an aluminium channel to hold those

Comment: Your question is really poorly worded. and What compound is it that you would like to know is ok on top of that adhesives .. Just an FYI if the adhesive is on the strip - then the strip will need to conduct through the 3M adhesive and then through "compound" .

Comment: @Ken The compound is a thermal glue, an example of the compound could be Arctic Silver Thermal 2 part glue which contains thermal page and epoxy. I want the heat to dissipate through the ceramic tile but wondering if the 3m Adhesive is going to have any negative effect on the conductivity of heat when used with the thermal glue, but I'm now thinking it may be better to use an aluminium plate stuck to the tile using thermal glue and then stick the LEDS using the 3M tape adhesive to the aluminium.

Comment: Ceramic is an insulator, not a thermal conductor.  It doesn't conduct heat well and will provide no real benefit as a heat sink.  Using Arctic Silver against the ceramic is just a waste of Arctic Silver.

Comment: @fixer1234 How is that so? ceramic and stone the go-to material for under the floor heating? if they worked as a insulator heat would transfer and the room would remain cold, furthermore ceramic is also used in a range of applainces and devices, such frying pans.

Comment: All materials conduct or transfer heat.  Conductors do it quickly and insulators do it slowly.  The insulation in your house doesn't block the transfer of heat, it just slows it down.  Ceramic cookware is slower to heat and cool, and as a side effect, provides very even heat.  Stone is used for passive heating because a big mass of it is very cheap, and slow is a good speed for that purpose.  It has all day to absorb heat and can release it slowly all night.  Phase change materials are much more effective (can store more energy).  (cont'd)

Comment: A big hunk of metal would release its heat quickly rather than over the course of a whole night.  For heat sink purposes, you want something that will move heat away quickly and give it up easily so it can move more.  Ceramic will "saturate" in the hot locations and act like a thermal blanket, doing the opposite of what you want.